# Salvar dados de um vetor em outro vetor em C

Tags: c

Eu tenho um código onde estou lendo caractere por caractere dentro de um arquivo e salvando eles dentro de um vetor chamado "entrada". Eu estou usando uma vírgula(o caractere 44 da tabela ASCII) como caractere de parada, então eu vou lendo os caracteres do arquivo e armazenando todos no vetor "palavras" enquanto eu não encontrar um vírgula, quando eu encontro a virgula eu paro de ler os caracteres e tenho um if que compara o conteúdo que foi já salvo nesse vetor "entrada" com as palavras que quero encontrar, por exemplo "abacaxi", se a string dentro do meu vetor "entrada" for igual a "abacaxi" ele apresenta um prinft na tela com "Encontrei abacaxi" e limpa o meu vetor, senão ele passa para o próximo if.

Eu preciso fazer com que cada vez que a string de caracteres que tenho dentro do meu vetor "entrada" for igual a string de caracteres que estou comparando dentro do meu if eu salve essa string do vetor "entrada" como posição de um novo vetor chamado "vetornovo".
Por exemplo: 
Foram lidos os caracteres do meu arquivo e eles formaram a string "abacaxi", eu comparo essa string dentro do meu if e verifico que ela foi encontrada, aí eu preciso copiar ela do vetor "entrada" como uma nova posição dentro do vetor "vetornovo". Nesse caso deveria ficar: vetornovo[0] = "abacaxi".

Esse é o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int caractere;
    int i=0;
    int v=0;
    char entrada[100] = "";
    char limpa;

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("arq.txt", "r");

    if (arquivo){
      do
      {
        caractere = fgetc(arquivo);
        if(caractere != 44)  {
            entrada[i++] = caractere;
        }else{
            if(strcmp(entrada, "abacaxi")==0){
                printf("\nEncontrado abacaxi\n", entrada); 
                for(v=0; v<10; v++)
                    entrada[v]=limpa;
            }else if(strcmp(entrada, "manga")==0){
                printf("\nEncontrada manga\n", entrada); 
                for(v=0; v<10; v++)
                    entrada[v]=limpa;
            }else if(strcmp(entrada, "laranja")==0){
                printf("\nEncontrada laranja\n", entrada); 
                for(v=0; v<10; v++)
                    entrada[v]=limpa;
            }else if(strcmp(entrada, "morango")==0){
                printf("\nEncontrado morango\n", entrada); 
                for(v=0; v<10; v++)
                    entrada[v]=limpa;
            }
            for(v=0; v<10; v++)
                entrada[v]=limpa;
            i=0;
        }   
      }while(!feof(arquivo));   
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Você não trata o fim do arquivo. Você não atribuiu nada à variável `limpa`, portanto ela irá conter lixo de memória, que depois irá atribuir a seus arrays. Na realidade para limpar uma string bastaria mover o caractere '\0' para a primeira posição do array, será considerada uma string de comprimento 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma opção é criar uma matriz(em q cada linha vai ser uma string)

```
int j=0;//contador para as linhas
char vetornovo[TAMANHO][100];
//tamanho seria quantas linhas vc acha q teria(o ideal seria fazer alocação dinamica)
```

para copiar uma string em outra usa a função strcpy,pode usar isso dentro de cada verificação

```
strcpy(vetornovo[j],entrada);
j++;//ja q a primeira posição(linha da matriz) esta ocupada incrementa pra proxima
```

dentro do if nãp precisa ter esse for em todas verificação ja que ele esta no final do if ele é executado de qualquer maneira

```
for(v=0; v<10; v++)
    entrada[v]=limpa;
i=0;
```